# n-form density weight of the levi civita tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

Why does the n form of levi civita $\epsilon:$=$w_{1}\wedge w_{2} ...\wedge w_{n}$ have a density of weight -1 where $w_{i}$'s are cobasis of some vector basis? I thought this geometrical quantity will have undefined weight which depends upon the vector basis's orientation. So it may have either +1 or -1 as the density weight which depends upon the orientation of the vector basis.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but you can find a fairly complete one in [this](http://phys.columbia.edu/~cyr/notes/Electrodynamics/CPope-DiffForms-p56-67.pdf) note. This MO [question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/165018/6048) has a nice [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/165019/6048) too.

Comment: But it depends. You have to choose a determinant.